# Login issue in chrome browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, browser-cache

I am facing a strange issue. I have developed an application in CodeIgniter. It works fine on my local system and on demo server. But when I move the script to live server the issue arises.

**The issue is :**
*I can login to my application from firefox, internet explorer, safari browser. But when I try to login using chrome, session destroyed after login and redirected to login page.*

I cleared browser catche, still issue exist.

URL : http://www.hcpdev.com/demo/user/login

User : ED_ZIELINSKI@clientDemo.com

Password : 12345

Comment: Do you have any code that you can show?

Comment: I have code. But I don't think its an code issue. because It works fine with firefox, internet explorer and safari. Only issue with chrome browser.

Comment: Could you please share url with user id and password for testing

Comment: URL : http://www.hcpdev.com/demo/user/login
User : ED_ZIELINSKI@clientDemo.com
Password : 12345

Comment: what session did you use? php or ci itself?

Comment: I have used CI Session

Comment: can you upload code of your controller($_SESSION code will be good)

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue . I just replace the `system/libraries/Session.php` file with this file and my problem is solved.

[libraries/Session.php](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/b211adee89f5fd2192051e9c0826146bd150f469/system/libraries/Session.php)

Just replace you session.php file with this file.

Honestly say i don't know what changes in this file to make is workable. But problem is solved

Comment: Still issue. Not fixed

Comment: Have you set this `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;` ?? in config file

Comment: $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200; is it okay?

Comment: yes change it to `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0` and try

Comment: are you sure problem is with your session or some other problem??

Comment: Read my question 1st. My Login is working with Firefox, Internet Explorer and Safari, But not working in Chrome?